# EF Improve performance of Many-to-Many / .Include .ThenInclude

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I've got a relatively basic model - Users and Tags. There is a fixed list of Tags. A User can have multiple Tags and a Tag can be used by multiple users.

I had gone with structure below and finding performance issues when returning results.

```
public class User
{
     public string Id {get; set;}
     public virtual List<UserTag> UserTags {get; set}
}

public class UserTag
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag{ get; set; }
}


public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserTag> UserTags { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following query which is takings a long time (several seconds):

```
var x = db.Users.Include(u => u.UserTags).ThenInclude(u => u.Trait).ToList<User>();
```

I have tried writing it as such, which has improved the time, however it is still taking too long:

```
db.UserTags.Load();
db.Tags.Load();
var x = db.Users.ToList<User>();
```

Is there any other way to speed this up? Running a query directly in SQL SMS is almost instant (e.g.

```
select * from Users u left outer join UserTags t on t.UserId = u.Id)
```

In terms of data rows, it is apx Tags: 100, UserTags:50,000, Users: 5,000

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables?

Comment: What's the context of the query? What are you trying to return?

Comment: How many users do you have? Why do you load all of them? Have you tried `AsSplitQuery()`?

Comment: Well, the SQL query you've shown is not equivalent - it does not return `Tag` fields for instance. Also EF probably adds some `ORDER BY` needed to produce the objects with nested collections result, while the result set of the SQL you are testing is flat. Also running "instant" is just the query, or retrieving all the results.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I'm trying to get back all Users and their Tag Names

Answer (score 0):

First you can check how EF translates your request to SQL Server - therefore use the "SQL Server Profiler"

Then you could use the genereated query to check if there might be an missing index which speeds up the query

You also can try to write a Join instead of ThenInclude and see how the query then behaves

best regards
Jimmy

Comment: Thanks - how could I translate it to a Join? I'm struggling to see where to add the join

Comment: You already wrote your query in SQL including the join???!